# angularjs ngstrap conflict when using dropdown and tooltip together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm using [ngstrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) There is a conflict between  and tooltip on ngstrap.

The problem that i want to get value of  using ng-model. but when I am using ngstrap tooltip the ng-model didn't work.

Hint : when I remove bs-tooltip tag from code dropdown work
my code in plunker [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LZNCdiyK11Xf3PUrw9Yp?p=preview)